# WP job manager plugin, location search to search address only?

Tags: wordpress, google-places-api

Using the WP job manager plugin with Extended Locations. I'm trying to find a way to show addresses only when user types in location, exclude businesses, restaurants, bars, hotels, etc.

Already had a look at Google places API, I can see that the API is called from different files (class-wp-job-manager-geocode.php and wp-job-manager-extended-location.php) but changes to these 2 files don't seem to make any difference.

Any other ideas?